# How do you graph the definite integral of 1/x from -1 to 1?

Tags: tikz-pgf, asymptote, fillbetween, integral

I want to make a graph of the function 1/x with the area under the curve shaded, but I have absolutely no idea how to do that since the curve isn't continuous. Optimally, the negative area and positive area would be shaded with different colors. I would also like there to be a label that says f(x)=1/x. I made this image in Desmos to show an example of the image I'm trying to get:
[image: graph of the area under the curve f(x)=1/x]

Comment: the first example of 2D graphs with Asymptote: https://asymptote.sourceforge.io/gallery/2Dgraphs/

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You are a new contributor so it would be better if I direct you to a more professional tool than `tkz-fct`. My package is only useful for small graphs. I think `pgfplots` is what you need. I think you will get answers with this one.

To be complete with `tkz-fct` you need to install `gnuplot`. This is what does the calculations. Otherwise you can do what you need with just `TikZ`.

updated : with `xstep` different from 1 use `x` and not `x`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tkz-fct}

\begin{document}
 \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=2]  
  \tkzInit[xmin=-4,xmax=4,ymin=-4,ymax=4,xstep=2,ystep=2]
  \tkzClip[space=1]
 \tkzGrid
  \tkzAxeXY
  \begin{scope}
    \tkzFct[color=blue, domain=0:4]{1./\x}
    \tkzFct[draw=none, domain=0:4]{0}
    \tkzDrawAreafg[color=blue!10,domain = 0.01:4]
  \end{scope}
  \begin{scope}
    \tkzFct[draw=none, domain=-4:0]{0}
    \tkzFct[color=red ,domain=-4:0]{1./\x}  
  \tkzDrawAreafg[color=red!20,domain = -4:-0.01]
   \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Complement :

You can mix tkz-fct and TikZ

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tkz-fct,mathtools}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=3] 
\tkzInit[xmin=0,xmax=4,ymin=-1.5,ymax=1.5] 
 \tkzAxeX\tkzAxeY
\tkzDefPoint(1,0){x} 
\tkzDrawPoint[color=blue,size=0.6pt](x) 
\shade[top color=gray!80,bottom color=gray!20] (1,0)%
    plot[id=ln,domain=1:2.718] function{log(x)} |-(1,0); 
\draw[color=blue] plot[id=ln,domain=0.2:4,samples=200]function{log(x)};
\tkzText[draw,color= black,fill=brown!50](2,-1)%
    {$\mathcal{A} = \int_1^{\text{e}}\ln(x)\text{d}x =\big[x\ln(x)\big]_{1}^{\text{e}} = \text{e}$}
\tkzText[draw,color= black,fill=brown!50](2,0.3){$\mathcal{A}$}
 \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Sorry, I'm completely new to this. I have ```gnuplot``` installed but I get an error in my log file that says ```runsystem(gnuplot "Cauchy Principal Value.tkzfonct.gnuplot")...disabled (restri
cted).``` so I don't think it is connecting to TeXShop properly. How do I solve this?

Comment: @mlxd41 1. Go to the Preferences. 2. Go to Tab "Engine"  3. Go to Field "pdfTeX"
4. In the LaTeX Input Field add --shell-escape at the end. Something like this :`pdflatex --file-line-error --synctex=1 --shell-escape`

Comment: @mlxd41  It is necessary to authorize the call to `gnuplot`. It's possible that you will have an alert then you must agree to the `shell-escape`

Comment: It worked, though I had to change the page from the default light grey color to white so that you can't see the white highlight box around each number on the graph axis. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Actually, something I just noticed: the graph isn't entirely accurate. It should go through the point (1,1) and (-1,1), but it looks like it goes just above and below those points respectively. Do you know why that is?

Comment: @mlxd41  Sorry I'm too busy with geometry and I don't use my old packages much anymore so I forget ... When you use `xstep` you have to write `\x` and not `x`.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a plain Asymptote way that you can compile [online](http://asymptote.ualberta.ca/). Plain things are suitable for beginners. Here is a [link on overleaf](https://www.overleaf.com/read/hmvcdgyfktmg). If you want to compile on desktops, make sure having [Asymptote](https://sourceforge.net/projects/asymptote/) installed.

[image]

```
// copy http://asymptote.ualberta.ca/ and click Run
usepackage("amsmath");  // for \dfrac
import graph;
import math; // for grid
unitsize(1cm);
size(6cm);
real f(real x){return 1/x;}
int a=4;
add(shift(-a,-a)*scale(2)*grid(a,a,gray));

real s=.1;
path p=graph(f,s,a);
path q=graph(f,-a,-s);
pen penp=magenta, penq=deepcyan;
fill((0,0)--(0,a+1)--p--(a+1,0)--cycle,penp+white+opacity(.5));
fill((0,0)--(-a-1,0)--q--(0,-a-1)--cycle,penq+opacity(.5));
draw(p,penp+1pt);
draw(q,penq+1pt);

clip(box((a,a),(-a,-a)));

draw(Label("$x$",EndPoint,align=SW),(-a-1,0)--(a+1,0),Arrow(TeXHead));
draw(Label("$y$",EndPoint,align=SW),(0,-a-.5)--(0,a+1),Arrow(TeXHead));
label(Label("p.v. $\displaystyle\int_{-a}^a\dfrac{1}{x}\,dx=0$",FillDraw(yellow,black)),(-2,2));
label(Label("$a$",Fill(white)),(a,0),2S);
label(Label("$-a$",Fill(white)),(-a,0),2N);
```